# Cannot get into specified URL

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

I have big problem. Before adding another controller (`Worksite`), I could get into this URL:

```
localhost:8080/api/user/10/vacation
```

But now, after add a new controller which is listening on: `/api/user/{id}/work-site`
I cannot get into `localhost:8080/api/user/10/vacation`

I am getting this error exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-08-02T19:02:40.432+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "HHH000142: Bytecode enhancement failed: com.springproject27.springproject.user.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Bytecode enhancement failed: com.springproject27.springproject.user.User",
  "path": "/api/user/10/vacation"
}
```

My Controller which contains this path is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/{userId}/vacation", produces =    "application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VacationController {

@Autowired
private VacationService vacationService;


@GetMapping
public List<Vacation> getVacations(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return vacationService.findAllByUserId(userId);
}
```

My VacationService with annotations and method which is used in controller:

```
@Transactional
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class VacationService {

@Autowired
private VacationRepository vacationRepository;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public List<Vacation> findAllByUserId(Long userId) {
    return vacationRepository.findByUserId(userId);
}
```

Comment: you got hibernate error. add more code what you did

Comment: done I think it's enough ?

Comment: Are you getting list of Vacation on your controller ? Try debugging .I believe Error is on your service.

Comment: Yes, when I am on  localhost:8080/api/user -> I have vacations.